# Timeout when submitting tx to the blockchain

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, stellar-sdk

I have running stellar core and stellar horizon together. Sometimes (recently even more) I am receiving such a response when trying to push tx to the blockchain. How could I approach this issue or prevent it form happening in the future? Appreciate any hint.

Response:

```
time="2021-09-06T12:18:56.686Z" level=warning msg="Cleared submission due to timeout" hash=b28b33da969afcc45fbb4ad69e2eaefb9e71a531976193b8706b43b7de0a3e52 listeners=1 pid=67 service=txsub.submissionList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timeout happens when Horizon did not receive an update for a given transaction submission from Stellar-Core. This can happen because of two reasons:

1. Transaction was not included in the ledger for 30 seconds. This usually means that the fee was too low.
2. Less likely: Stellar-Core lost sync with the network after transaction was submitted. In such case Stellar-Core issue should be resolved. It's possible that the problem is temporary (ex. one of the nodes in the quorum set is down so there is no consensus).

Read more about [Timeout](https://developers.stellar.org/api/errors/http-status-codes/horizon-specific/timeout/) error in API reference.